# Can I upload my HTML/CSS/Javascript game onto a Wordpress page?

Tags: css, javascript, html

I've written a basketball simulator game in plain HTML/CSS/Javascript. I also have a Wordpress site. Can I upload my game, so my visitors can play it?

I know that if I had written my website from scratch, this would be easy. So, how can I wrestle WordPress into letting me upload my simple game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). It has a PHP comment that tells WordPress its name as a template. The page doesn't have to have any PHP code, and you can fill it with your HTML instead, which can link to CSS/JS files that you upload separately.

Then in WordPress you create a page and choose this template — et voila, you have your game on the site.